# spring batch with multiple datasources at runtime

Tags: java, datasource, spring-batch

I have to crawl across some configured databases in a table . where each record specifies a schema to be read from . So we have to poll the table and run the job appropriately.

thought to use Spring batch(JdbcPagingItemReader) to read data from all the Schema's configured. if i have to configure this, How can i do it using Spring Batch ?

should i take multiple jobs with different reader for each database to read from, or is there any way where i can send the datasource at runtime for the Spring Batch to read data from ?

How can i manage Multiple databases for Single Spring Batch. If not is there any other suggestion for the Database Crawling(or Harvesting)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 solutions using Spring Batch :

- Pass the `DataSource` properties (url, username, password....) at runtime through `JobParameters`. This means that the reading logic of the first read (the one which tells you what to read) has to be done outside the job
- Have a job with 2 steps, the first one doing the "metadata" read and storing result in the `JobExecutionContext` and the second one doing the actual read using previously stored values at runtime

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but i have solved it in a diffferent way. i have ovverridden setDatasource() of JdbcPagingItemReader and injected a datasource value depending on the Jobparameter key. So i have simply mapped key names to Datasource names in a database and process accrodingly at runtime.   and as u said i can also build a datasource depending on the Jobparametrs in SetDataSource method , but it is not that safe to put the database passwords anywhere else

Answer (score 1):

If you are just running a query to get some data to then run other queries then this is not really something that aligns with what Spring Batch does.   That just a standard JDBC or JPA type DAO/Service setup.   You can use Quartz or Spring Scheduler to set a CRON value for when you what it to check the table(s).

Comment: @BrainC i am nt just running a query , it has a processor followed by a writer. anyway thank you Brian.my problem is solved